# Replace busy waiting with condition variable

Tags: pthreads

How can I replace the below busy waiting with condition variables?

```
while (this_thread != pthread_self()){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        if(this_thread == -1)
            this_thread = get_id();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you set the value returned by `get_id()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the value returned by `get_id()` is **only** set via a function called `set_id()`, please see this pseudo code:

globals

```
Mutex mutex
Condition cond
Id id
```

code

```
set_id(id_in)
{
  mutex_lock
  id = id_in
  cond_signal
  mutex_unlock
}

test()
{
  mutex_lock
  while ((this_thread = get_id()) != pthread_self())
    cond_wait
  mutex_unlock
}
```